# カスタムデータ属性のname設定について

Tags: javascript

簡単な問題なのですが、うまくいかないので質問させていただきます。

例えば
ウィンドウの高さが1000pxのとき

```
<div data-1000="a">
```

ウィンドウの高さが500pxのとき

```
<div data-500="a">
```

上記のようにHTMLのカスタムデータ属性のnameにウィンドウの高さを付与したいのですが、うまくいきません。
分かる方よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何を達成したいのか、どううまくいかないのかわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

色々はっきりしない部分はありますが
こんな感じですかね。

```js
var height = window.innerHeight;
var theDiv = document.getElementById("it");

//setAttributeを使う場合
var att_name = "data-" + height;
theDiv.setAttribute(att_name, "a");
console.log(theDiv.getAttribute(att_name));
console.log(theDiv.outerHTML);
theDiv.removeAttribute(att_name);//削除
console.log(theDiv.outerHTML);

//dataset IDL属性の場合
var name = "h" + height;//数字で始まる名前は使用できない。
theDiv.dataset[name]="a";
console.log(theDiv.dataset[name]);
console.log(theDiv.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="it">...</div>
```

参照：[独自データ属性](http://www.html5.jp/tag/attributes/data.html)

ノート：
属性名として「使用出来る文字について数字で始まる名前が使用できる」と指摘があったので、
改めて調べて見ました。

> 独自データ属性は、名前空間に属さない属性で、その名前は文字列 "data-" で始まり、ハイフンの後に少なくとも一文字が続きます。これは
>   XML 互換で、ASCII 大文字 を含みません。

[原文](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)：

> .2.5.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes
>
> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is [XML-compatible](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#xml-compatible), and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.

XML 互換(XML-compatible)の名前

> Attribute names are said to be XML-compatible if they match the [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name)
>   production defined in XML, they contain no ":" (U+003A) characters,
>   and their first three characters are not an ASCII case-insensitive
>   match for the string "xml". [XML]

ここで言う
名前(Name):

> ```
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
> Name ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

これから、「名前」が数字から始まってはいけない。xmlで始まってはいけない、コロン(:)や記号は使えないとなります。
この[サイト](https://www.marguerite.jp/Nihongo/WWW/RefHTML/Attrs/data-XXX.html#ATTR_NAME)がわかりやすいです。

なので、「規格上は数字で始まる名前は使用できない」ということになると思います。
数字を指定しても動作する(Chromeで試してみました）のは、
おそらく、data-を含めた全体としてはhtml5の属性名としてバリッド（なので、setAttributeを使う場合にはＯＫ）だからじゃないかと思いますが、使用しない方がいいです。

Comment: datasetプロパティへの代入は、ハイフン直後のascii小文字だけが禁止されているだけで、a-zから始まるという制約はありません
なので element.dataset[1] = '1' は正常に機能するはずです

Comment: @gocho 例えば`"h"`を`"H"`に変更した場合望むような結果が得られません。また、`"?"`などは実行ができません。 スニペットをコピーして実際に試してみて下さい。

Comment: @gocho 数字のみでも動作するようですね。

Comment: 「ハイフン直後のascii小文字だけが禁止」は、多分「ハイフン直後のascii大文字だけが禁止」のタイポ間違いですね。

Comment: @gocho 規格を調べて見ました。やはり数字で始まる名前は使用出来ないようです。

Comment: 長くなりそうなので、別の質問にします

Comment: IDL では elm.dataset['foo-bar'] のような「ハイフン直後のascii小文字」は SyntaxError になります
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-dataset

Comment: @gocho  ああなるほど、そのことを言っていたのですね。それは名前の変換規則にしたがって変換しないとだめですね。

Comment: [WHATWGのsetitemアルゴリズム](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-domstringmap-setitem) のstep4.をみると「XML互換の名前」が意味するのは、step3で`data-`が前に挿入された後の名前であるのは明らかですが、該当する規格での同じ部分[ワーキングドラフト](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#dom-dataset) にも、[W3C Recommendation 28 October 2014](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#dom-dataset) にも、(ここで「"InvalidCharacterError" DOMException」を起こすとか)そんなことは書いてないんですよね。私の見ているHTML5規格が古いのかRecommendation だからでしょうか？